# Typescript undefined validation in inner function

Tags: typescript

I have this block of code (simplified), but i dont known if i doing it the wrong way or is something iam misunderstanding.

```js
  const user = fetchUserFromSomeWhere()
  try {
    validateUser(user)
  } catch (e) {
    return response.status(400).send('user error')
  }

  console.log(user.name) // TS2532: Object is possibly 'undefined'.
```

My `fetchUserFromSomeWhere()` could be `undefined`, so when i try to use some of the `user` property TS give me the error `TS2532: Object is possibly 'undefined'.` i understand his point of view, but my `validateUser(user)` already check it for `undefined` among other things.

So my question is: Theres a way to tell the compiler that the user is already validated? Whats the right/better way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to provide the full code, and to trust the TS Errors, because they can be very helpfull in many situations, also I would suggest to you to log the output of both `fetchUserFromSomeWhere` and `validateUser` functions, are those `async` functions by any chance ?